# Check to see if a value is present, then copy to another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to take a rough list of data, then copy it into a pre-formatted, organized form. To do this, I have the rough list set up so that each item on the list is numbered in order, no matter if there are spaces between items. The macro I am trying to make will take that rough list and copy it to the form without any spaces. Bear with me, I have been trying to teach myself Visual Basic, so the code I have may be... messy. Currently, the problem that I am having is that I get an overflow on i = i + 1.

```
Sub Print_Sheet_Populate()
'
' Print_Sheet_Populate Macro
' Takes Items from Raw Data sheet and puts them in Print Sheet sheet.
'

'
Dim wsS1 As Worksheet
Dim wsS2 As Worksheet
Dim ending As Long
Dim copy() As Long
Dim i As Long

Set wsS1 = Sheets("Raw Data")
Set wsS2 = Sheets("Print Sheet")

With wsS1.Range("A:A") 'To copy the item numbers in the rough data to an array
    i = 1
        Set c = .Find(i, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            ReDim copy(i)
            copy(i - 1) = c.Value
            Do
                i = i + 1
                ending = i
            Loop While Not c Is Nothing
        End If
End With

With wsS2.Range("A24:A324") 'To paste the data from the array to the form
    i = 1
        If Not i = ending Then
            Do
                Worksheets("wsS2").Range("A" & i).Value = copy(i - 1)
                i = i + 1
            Loop While Not c Is Nothing
        End If
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from [Range.Find Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx):

> When the search reaches the end of the specified search range, it
>   wraps around to the beginning of the range. To stop a search when this
>   wraparound occurs, save the address of the first found cell, and then
>   test each successive found-cell address against this saved address.

Comment: Glad it help you! Have you tried replacing the first first loop with a sort of the data, and to replace the second loop with something like that `Range.resize(ubound(array),ubound(array,2)).value=Array` to post the entire array at once?